# Probability of combinations of numbers on three cards

Tags: probability

Kitty has a pack of 16 numbered cards. Each card has a single number written on it. Four cards are labelled '1', four cards are labelled '2', four cards are labelled '3' and four cards are labelled '4'. She shuffles the pack then deals a hand of 3.

What is the probability that

a) The three numbers are all the same?

b) The three numbers add to 11?

c) The three numbers are consecutive?

---

Progress:       For the first one I know we can have $(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)$ but I don't know how many arrangements there are in total.

For b) I don't know how to count all the ones that add up to 11.

For c) I know we can have $(1, 2, 3)$, and $(2, 3, 4)$ but I don't know the total.

Comment: For the first one I know we can have (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4) but I don't know how many arrangements there are in total.

Comment: for b) I dont know how to count all the ones that add up to 11. For c) I know we can have (1, 2, 3), and (2, 3, 4) but I don't know the total

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the cards a distinct, when a new hand is dealt there are 16 choices for the first card, 15 choices for the second card and 14 choices for the third card, giving $16\times15\times14=3360$ different deals.  Since the order of these choices does not matter and since there are $3\times2\times1=6$ different orderings of the same set of three cards the total number of distinct hands is $3360/6=560$ This is in fact the binomial coefficient $\binom{16}{3}$.  I hope this helps.

Comment: But 560 is not a probability?..

Comment: No, but in your first case you have identified 4 out of these 560 hands that works!

Comment: Ohh I see so 560 is the total number!

Comment: How would you count the total number of dealings which add up to 11 though?

Comment: 4+4+2+1 is one pattern, 4+3+3+1 is another. You can systematically count the others.

Comment: But there would be way too many to count, is there not a formula I can use?

Comment: Only three cards, my bad.  There are only 24 such patterns. The only number that work are 4+4+3.  Now, assuming the cards are distinct how many different hands give these numbers?

Comment: We can have (4, 4, 3), (4, 3, 4), (3, 4, 4)